# 'Tables' not recognizing 'isHDF5File'

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5

I am writing a code that creates an HDF5 that can later be used for data analysis. I load the following packages:

```
import numpy as np
import tables
```

Then I use the tables module to determine if my file is an HDF5 file with:

```
tables.isHDF5File(FILENAME)
```

This normally would print either TRUE or FALSE depending on if the file type is actually an HDF5 file or not. However, I get the error:

> AttributeError: module 'tables' has no attribute 'isHDF5File'

So I tried:

```
from tables import isHDF5File
```

and got the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'isHDF5File'

I've tried this code on another computer, and it ran fine. I've tried updating both numpy and tables with pip but it states that the file is already up to date. Is there a reason 'tables' isn't recognizing 'isHDF5File' for me? I am running this code on a Mac (not working) but it worked on a PC (if this matters).

Comment: Have you called one of your scripts `tables.py`? If so, rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the function name right?

```
In [21]: import tables
In [22]: tables.is_hdf5_file?
Docstring:
is_hdf5_file(filename)

Determine whether a file is in the HDF5 format.

When successful, it returns a true value if the file is an HDF5
file, false otherwise.  If there were problems identifying the file,
an HDF5ExtError is raised.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
In [23]:
```